# In A.JAVA file, Can i access one class Object in B.java file?

Tags: java

As a beginner to Java, i want to ask a question

In A.java (for example Employee.java)

```
import java.io.*;
public class Employee{
   public String name;
   private double salary;
   public Employee (String empName){
      name = empName;
   }
   public void setSalary(double empSal){
      salary = empSal;
   }  
   // 打印信息
   public void printEmp(){
      System.out.println("名字 : " + name );
      System.out.println("薪水 : " + salary);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      Employee empOne = new Employee("RUNOOB");
      empOne.setSalary(1000);
      empOne.printEmp();
   }
}
```

In B.java (for example TestEmployee.java)

Do i need say something like include A.java for use object Employee?

```
EmployeeJack= new Employee();
 EmployeeJack.name="testName";
System.out.println(EmployeeJack.name);
```

Comment: You can't put your `Employee` class in `A.java`. That needs to be in `Employee.java`; what happened when you tried your `B.java`?

Comment: In Java, Employee is defined in `Employee.java`
In B.java, you need to import `Employee.java`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import anything if the two classes are in the same package. Otherwise, use import statement with the package name and class name

```
import com.foo.bar.Employee
```

Comment: And similarly for inner classes, also include the parent class in the import. `import java.util.Map.Entry;`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object reference of the class which will force you to import the class.
You then can use the object reference to call the variable ie.

Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.'variable';